# What is the difference between mentioned 2 examples generics?

Tags: java, generics

I am learning generics in java. I am little bit confused over 2 samples as mentioned below. Sample one is

```
public class TrickyName <X extends Object>{
    private X x;
    public TrickyName(X x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    private double getDouble() {
        return x.doubleValue();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TrickyName<Integer> a = new TrickyName<Integer>(new Integer(1));
        System.out.print(a.getDouble());
    }
}
```

sample 2

```
public class TrickyName <X extends Number>{
    private X x;
    public TrickyName(X x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    private double getDouble() {
        return x.doubleValue();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TrickyName<Integer> a = new TrickyName<Integer>(new Integer(1));
        System.out.print(a.getDouble());
    }
}
```

in mentioned samples, there is just a difference of extending class.In first sample, I am extending Object in second sample extending from Number. What I understand is X extend Object means anything that extends object(since every class extends object) can be used so, Integer class is used here and in getDouble() in first sample is giving compilation error but when I extend  from Number class as mentioned in second sample it works. Why is that so? Number class and integer class both extends from Object. Where I am wrong please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `X extends Object`, that requires that `X` be a subclass of [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) (usually a safe assumption). When you say `X extends Number`, then the type must be a more specific `Number` type.

`Object` doesn't have a `doubleValue()` method. `Number` does have [`Number.doubleValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue--) which is why that works.